# Does secure LWE implementation leak bit information?

Tags: rsa, cryptanalysis, discrete-logarithm, post-quantum-cryptography, lwe

We know RSA leaks one bit about the factors and improper yet secure implementations of Discrete Logarithm leak one bit about the discrete logarithm. Does LWE leak any information?

Comment: Could you cite references to something outlining those leaked bits? Not that I'm doubting you, but references would be nice for those of us that don't already know that off-hand.

Comment: LSB of odd factors is 1 and LSB of discrete log is easy in certain situations and these are standard.